# Where clause as variable in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, where-clause

I am trying to create a more advanced query in Laravel 4, which consists of AND and OR where clauses, in the following format:

```
(('a','=','1') OR ('b','=','s') OR ('c','=','3')) AND (('d','=','1') OR ('e','=','s') OR ('f','=','3'))
```

The problem is that I am generating these queries on the fly, based on some filters the user applies through some forms. This means that the query can have the following format:

```
a AND b
```

as well as this format:

```
(a OR b OR c) AND (d OR e OR f)
```

as well as this one:

```
(a OR b) AND c AND (d OR e) AND f
```

I am generating the where clause as a string, but I cannot manage to add this variable to the method call.

Example:

```
$whereclause = where(function($query){$query->where('colorgrade','like','41-2');})->where(function($query){$query->where('datetime','>','2014-11-05');})

$result = $gin->bales()->$whereclause->take(1000)->get();
```

The error I am getting is the following:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$where(function($query){$query->where('colorgrade','like','41-2');})->where(function($query){$query->where('datetime','>','2014-11-05');})

How can I pass the generated where clause (string variable) to the above chaining functions?

Answer (score 1):

To create queries on the fly, is a good ideia make use of Eloquent Query Scopes.
That's provide a way for you to build different queries based on, for example, form options.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do it like this, however I have a hunch this doesn't work with closures and chained methods in the variable. See http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

```
$result = $gin->bales()->$whereclause()->take(1000)->get();
```

Alternativly you can split up the query so its not all done within a single line.

```
// Get the initial Query Builder instance
$query = $gin->bales();

$query->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('colorgrade', 'like', '41-2');
});

if ($something === 'something') {
    $query->where('something', $something);
} else {
    $query->where('something', 'something_else');
}

// Finally get our results
$results = $query->take(1000)->get();
```